# Can anyone figure out a way to navigate a directory using this FTP Client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, ftp

So I downloaded an FTP Client from code project, but I cannot figure out a way to navigate through the directories.  The project link is at the bottom of the post.

Anyways, I am logging on to an FTP server with the following information

```
ServerIP: ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us
Username: anonymous
Password: youremail@gmail.com
```

I need to navigate to the "pub" folder (i.e. it's the only folder where I have permission to write, delete, rename, make directories, etc), but there is no way to click on a directory and traverse said directory.

For reference, the directories look as such:

```
README
lost+found
pub
public
...etc
```

I want to be able to click on the pub folder and see everything in pub.  I'm not sure if this was originally implemented in the project, but I want to be able to do this.

To accomplish navigating through the pub folder, I was thinking something along the lines of...

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.randomSite/text.txt");
```

However, I have zero experience with GUI and don't exactly know how to get this working when a user clicks on one of the directories listed above.

If someone could take a look at the project and figure out a way to traverse the directories using the GUI, I would be greatly indebted.

**EDIT: **

So I've tried the following:

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP;

try
{
ListBox b1 = (ListBox)sender;
reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + b1.Text);
```

which gives me the correct uri ftp://ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us/pub (I verified this in the watch window), but I am guessing the code below is suspect.

It throws an exception immediately when it tries to get the response.  I have no idea why as everything looks fine.

```
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
        Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        ftpStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        //Update current directory
        btnLstFiles_Click(sender, e);
```

which gives me the current

**Link to Project**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17202/Simple-FTP-demo-application-using-C-Net

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is handle a double-click event in `lstFiles` which would invoke a function that sends a command to the FTP server to change to the directory indicated by the clicked text.

I'm not familiar enough with the .Net FTP-related classes to know how to send the change directory command, so I would start by looking at the documentation for `FtpWebRequest`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.FtpWebRequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That is exactly what I have been doing, haha.  Still struggling. :(

Comment: I have the double click event and I have the code which should be at the end (i.e. update the current directory).  I cannot figure out how to change the current directory, however.

Comment: Do I do something like `ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + sender.ToString());`?  I'm confused on how I can capture the text that they clicked on.

Comment: Or could I just call the rename directory to rename the directory that was clicked?

Comment: Your example will work but you need to modify it because in the double-click event handler, `sender` is the handle to the list box and not the selected item. You will first need to query the listbox to see what item is selected then convert that to a string. You definitely do not want to rename the directory because that doesn't accomplish what you want. Not to mention that most public FTP sites don't give you rename permissions.

Comment: As an aside, this sample project is not a very good example for making an FTP client. It seems to me the way it works is it connects, issues a command, the disconnects. This is highly inefficient. You want to establish a connection, and while connected, issue other commands to navigate, download, etc. and only disconnect when you're all done.